# What are the last couple of lines in laravel that automatically added?

Tags: laravel

I have noticed that whenever I create a laravel project, laravel automatically ads html code at the end?

[image]

What is it? How to disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is not Laravel fault. Have you verified other pages source? Make sure this is not what this plugin https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copyfish-ocr-software/ adds automatically. Also you should verify this in other browser

Comment: yes, you are partially right. Switched to Firefox that got rid of some code but some code ui is still present. I think, jquery ui script might create this. Is it possible?

Comment: If you start fresh project, it's rather impossible. So either you have virus or you have some addons for browsers that add this

Comment: Actually, I am using the instant search feature from jquery ui and somehow that was creating  parts of it code. Just disabled <script> to jquery ui and that also removed code showing up at the bottom.